# Why not present continuous or "going to" for these events?

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous, future-time, will-vs-going-to

> This week, we are going on a trip to Europe.  First, we **will stop**  in London for five days. Then we  **fly** to Rome for two days.  After that, we **go**  to Vienna.

Why not present continuous if all has been planned before (hotel, plane ticket):

are stopping, are flying, are going

or going to

are going to stop  then (going to) fly, (going) to go

Comment: Present continuous is also perfectly fine for that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

We use **present simple** when we talk about *schedules, programs, etc. (for public transport, cinemas, etc.):*

> My train **leaves** at 11:30, so I need to be at the station by 11:15.
>   What time **does** the film **begin** this evening?
>   **It's** Wednesday tomorrow / Tomorrow **is** Wednesday.

You can use the **present simple** to talk about *people if their plans are fixed like a schedule*:

> I **start** my new job on Monday.
>   What time **do** you **finish** your work tomorrow?

**But** the **continuous** is ***more usual*** for *personal arrangements*.

> What time **are** you **meeting** Mohammad tomorrow (*not do you meet*)?

We use *I am **going** **to do** something* when we say *what we have decided to do, but probably not arranged to do*:

> "Your shoes are dirty." "Yes, I know. **I'm going to clean** them." (I've *decided* to clean them, but I *haven't arranged* to clean them)
>   I've decided not to stay here any longer. Tomorrow **I'm going to look** for somewhere else to stay.

***Often the difference between using "I am doing" or "I am going to do" is very small**, and either form is possible

About using **will** instead of **going to**, in general, we use **will** when we decide to do something *at the time of speaking*, but **sometimes there is not much difference between them**, such as the following examples:

> I think the weather **will be** sunny tomorrow.
>   I think the weather **is going to be** sunny tomorrow.

There is no difference between these two, or at least, not much difference.

But in the following example, we have to use **going to** since we are making a statement based on the current situation:

> Look at those black clouds in the sky. (I think) **It's going to rain**.
>
> (Black clouds are often a certain sign of raining)

We can also use **will** when *we are predicting the future*:

> Do you think Jill can pass the exam?
>   Yes, of course! She **will pass** it easily.

Here, we are not saying that Jill has decided to pass the exam, but we are saying what we think or know that will happen.

It is not related to this question, but it is worth mentioning that **will** can also be used about the current time. For example:

> Don't call Ann now, Kate. She'**ll be** busy.

It is my interpretation of why **will** has been used in the above example: To my way of thinking, Ann will be receiving the call in a few seconds from now, and *not now*; therefore, it is correct to use **will** instead of **is**.

I also found this usage of **will** in here (https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-m_future.htm)

The verb **be** is an exception with **will**. Even when we have a very firm plan, and we are not speaking spontaneously, we can use **will** with **be**. Look at these examples:

> I **will be** in London tomorrow.
>   There **will be** 50 people at the party.
>   The meeting **will be** at 9.30 am.

At the end, I don't understand why "will stop" has been used here. In every aspect that I look at it, it should be "stop." However, it is surely intelligible.

Ref. (with slight modifications):

Units 19, 20, 22, and 23 of *English Grammar in Use, Third Edition*

Comment: We use present progressive for activities in our current time frame (discussions of personal arrangements and fixed plans http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/presten4.html  stopping , flying and going are fixed pans

Comment: I think that" This week, we are going on a trip to Europe." is a fixed plan,so we don't need to re-precise that  the following actions  detailing the trip, are also fixed plans,  so we can use will, even if events have been planned before. Am I right ?

Comment: I will add an edit to the answer.

Comment: I think I  got it !  Will is better in that case because  the time is not specified

Comment: @user5577 Actually, I think "will" is partly used to telegraph the function of the upcoming present tenses as having a future sense. It could be in present tense as well, but it subtly (perhaps even subconsciously) orients the listener to place those verbs accurately in time.